# Using modulo for rows and columns

Tags: php, html, css, modulo

I know this question has been asked for several times, but I just can't get it right. All examples I have found are aither too personal and complicated or some angular or javascript. I am trying to learn how to set 4 columns inside a row.

```
 // start basic loop just to have some data
 <?php for($a=1; $a<=20; $a++) : ?>

    // set counter
    <?php $i=0; ?>

    <div class="row">

        <div class="col-md-3" style="border: 1px solid black">
            <?php echo $i; ?>
        </div>

        <?php if($i++ % 4 == 0) : ?>
        </div><div class="row">
    <?php endif; ?>

// close row
</div>

<?php endfor; ?>
```

Comment: What do you mean by *"set basic 4 columns inside a row"*?

Comment: You are resetting `$i=0;` on each loop of `$a`. So your `$i++` in `if($i++ % 4 == 0)` will never increase. You should be doing your checks on `$a`. What is the purpose of using `$i` as well?

Comment: Also, you should move your `<div class="row">` to before your loop, as currently you are doing a row on every loop of `$a`, and not just after 4.

Comment: Your comments should probably be HTML comments rather than PHP comments.

Comment: This is producing four rows for every column, instead of the other way around.

Comment: Your between-row sandwich `</div><div class="row">` needs to be PHP output for the if-endif tags to make it "conditional": `<?php echo "</div><div class=\"row\">" ?>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your PHP script is a little out, try the following

```
<div class="row">
    <?php
// start basic loop just to have some data
for($a=0; $a<=20; $a++) {
    ?>
    <div class="col-md-3" style="border: 1px solid black">
        <?php echo $a; ?>
    </div>
    <?php
    if($a % 4 == 3) {
    ?>
</div>
<div class="row">
    <?php
    }
}
    ?>
</div>
```

Comment: no, this doesn't change anything. There is 1 column per row, but every other row that row doesn't even have any column

Comment: @IvanTopić Have a try now. Try it out on phpfiddle :)

Answer (score 0):

Things can become easier if you create a loop for generating rows, and another for generating the cells within those rows, like this:

```
<?php   // start basic loop for generating rows
        for($row=0; $row<5; $row++) {
?>          <div class="row">
<?php       // start basic loop for cells within a row
            for($cell=0; $cell<4; $cell++) {
?>              <div class="col-md-3" style="border: 1px solid black">
                    <?=$row*4+$cell?>
                </div>
<?php       }
?>          </div>
<?php   }
?>
```

I assume you have a style for `col-md-3` that makes those `div` elements stay on one row, something like this:

```
<style>
    .col-md-3 { display: table-cell; width: 100px }
</style>
```